Should business logic classes be POJO only?
I read about three-tier architecture and I have a question: I read that in business logic (that is, what is in logic tier) there should be POJO classes, but in most Spring manuals these classes are not POJOs and sprinkled with all sorts of annotations or even inherit from the Spring classes. What is correct? Do I need to create some intermediate classes?
P.s.
By POJO I mean just a Java class without external dependencies on other libraries and frameworks, such as Spring.

I'm not sure everyone understands the term POJO the same way.  When the term was created, there were lots of (IMO stupid) reflective frameworks such as JavaBeans and invasive frameworks like EJBs (1.0, 1.1). The idea was that you could just use Java objects without all that garbage. Bizarrely, almost everyone at the time starting using it to mean JavaBean-style (getters and setters) but without the reflection.  I'd argue extending another normal Java class doesn't make something non-POJO. Annotations are less clear. Anything that changes compiled classes would probably qualify as non-POJO.


I read about three-tier architecture and I have a question: I read that in business logic (that is, what is in logic tier) there should be bare Java classes,

These bare Java classes are called POJO's (Plain Old Java Object). If you've chosen to use them then you're right, they aren't supposed to know about frameworks, or infrastructure, or much of anything really. They depend on very little. They depend on Java. They are very pure. That purity can be handy. That purity comes at a cost. Using POJO's won't eliminate dependencies. It will require that you move dependencies elsewhere.
If anyone told you that you're supposed to use POJO's then ask them why. If they don't mention the problem you're working on then don't take them too seriously.

in most Spring manuals these classes are sprinkled with all sorts of annotations or even inherit from the Spring classes.

Spring is wonderfully effective at what it does. It can be used in many ways. The people who write Spring manuals are motivated to encourage uses that are good for Spring. There are ways to use Spring that avoid vender lock in. For some reason instructions that provide for that need can be hard to find. Ignoring that need is a risk some choose to take.

What is correct?

Either can be justified. The only correct thing to do here is realize no book, blog or framework author has any idea what you're working on or your actual needs. You have to figure out what concerns are important to you, what costs are worth paying, and what risks are worth taking. None of this is easy.
My advice, master both ways of working. That will give you a better sense of the benefits and costs. It will help you see what problems and situations either fits better with.
I've tried to do this myself but have yet to come up with a good rule of thumb that would tell you when to pick which. I have found one persistent concern, if you're on a team then your pick needs to be something the rest of the team can support.

Spring is just a library/framework, is there any difference between Spring and the JDK, at the end of the day both are just code written by someone else...
If you take your argument to the next logical step, you could ask: Should you use any JDK classes in your business logic - or hand code everything using Object and primitives?
Obviously it is ludicrous to say that you are going to write your entire business tier without using any JDK classes, by extension a BLANKET STATEMENT that you are not going to include any classes from any third party framework will not stand up to critical review by any experienced software engineer.
The more interesting question is, which classes should you include from the JDK and third party libraries - that question could be paraphrased as "how do I design software" as such you are going to need to narrow it down to a question that can be answered...

The crux of the argument around business logic is one of separation of concerns we don't want the "meat" of what we are trying to express about our business domain muddied up with a bunch of plumbing code - which handle persistence and taking to other components/systems.
Frameworks are neutral in this, they can be force in either direction, they can help clean up the code so that you can focus on the logic or introduce a bunch of extra garbage.
Excluding all frameworks from the business tier saves you from the potential negative effects, but also prevents you from leveraging the benefits.

"is there any difference between Spring and the JDK, at the end of the day both are just code written by someone else..." The difference is that the JDK is (basically) always available in any Java runtime and Spring isn't.

You download the JDK, you download Spring - they are now both available...

You can't run Java without the JDK, but you can run it without Spring.

So the question is, "does someone need to run my business logic without Spring?". It's a bit of a high-falutin' question for my liking, and maybe there's some use cases where you want to fully isolate your business logic away from your Spring dependencies. Maybe you need to prove to your boss you've done your tiers right, and avoiding any Spring dependency is a discipline to avoid them mixing. Otherwise, you're never actually going to want to pick up your business logic and move it into a new application framework unchanged. Until one day your boss says you have to ;-)

Or to analyse it another way: what proportion of your code is in this logic layer? If you follow this rule and want to move off Spring, and 90% of your code is Spring-free business logic, you'll be very grateful. If you follow this rule and want to move off Spring and 90% of your code is in the presentation tier, you've saved yourself a marginal 10% of work, in a case that probably will never happen. YAGNI, move on. So, which one is this project?

If you choose to use Spring it often becomes a "core" dependency - the more you leverage it, the harder it becomes to reverse the decision, however the same can be said for the programming language itself - you always have the option of porting to another language. I questions the logic of saying we will use Spring in some parts of the application, but there are some parts of the application where you absolutely must not be use Spring ...

Well, and also what are you using out of Spring? One little helper function, that you could if necessary rewrite in an afternoon, then it makes no difference. It's probably arguable though, that if your business logic is shot throughout with Spring as a core dependency, then it is not a business logic tier. It's some other architecture of which the author of your textbook would strongly disapprove. Doesn't necessarily mean they're right to disapprove, but then why are you reading their book about three-tier architectures? ;-)

I think the term POJO is a distraction. It was basically a joke:

... We wondered why people were so against using regular objects in their systems and concluded that it was because simple objects lacked a fancy name. So we gave them one, and it's caught on very nicely.

In other words, it doesn't mean much of anything. The point was that Java, a Turing-complete language was perfectly capable of solving problems without fancy, invasive frameworks. This was long before Spring 'captured' Java.
So, I say you forget about what is and isn't a POJO and instead focus on whether you want or need your business logic be free of dependencies on frameworks like Spring. The reason to avoid such dependencies is simple: you need/want to use this business logic with a different framework or in some framework-free context.
The question is whether independence is worth the effort. Is there some hot new thing coming that will replace Spring or make it obsolete? Maybe but given how embedded Spring is in so many applications, it seems unlikely. It seems to me like a large number of Java developers can't build an application without Spring, or at least never consider that option. In any event, if something does supplant Spring, there's going to be a lot of code that needs to be refactored or even rewritten. You won't be alone.
But this argument also applies to other frameworks which are not as ubiquitous. Decoupling your core business logic from dependencies in general can add some more effort but can pay off when you want to eliminate a dependency.

"Decoupling your core business logic from dependencies in general can add some more effort but can pay off when you want to eliminate a dependency." - also there's a payoff whenever decoupling [some bit of code] from [some dependency] decouples that code from concerns that are the domain of [some dependency] but should not (per your design) be the domain of [some bit of code]. So, the point of a tiered architecture is to tell you that your presentation code shouldn't be messing with databases, and therefore shouldn't depend on database classes. And so on.

That is, even if you never want to change databases, still there are some potential advantages to separating off a data layer. The payoff is just the usual one from decoupling, that you don't have to mentally encompass the whole system to change one thing. The specific details of what classes are "allowed" in your business logic is one for each application to consider and plan.

@SteveJessop I agree with you. My experience tells me however that building a really nicely decoupled design takes a fair amount of skill and experience and many applications are not well-written enough in general to make reuse of the logic useful. And if you work on team with people who don't get it and/or are even aggressively against thinking ahead, they will sabotage such efforts anyway.

I was thinking about this again, and it occurs to me that actually there is a plausible reason to want to truly separate the business logic from Spring. Suppose that after finishing the three-tier architecture book, you move on to a microservices book. Then suddenly you're going to need to spin up loads of different JVMs for different bits of your application. You might not want the weight of Spring on all of them, so you pick a different web application framework ;-) And agreed, this will be a lot of work just to make components separable, aside from the devops work!

@SteveJessop I am not a fan of Spring. It's a big part of why I've lost interest in Java. Too many 'Spring programmers' insisting that everything must be done with Spring who are incredulous at the idea that it wouldn't be the cornerstone of every application. I think it's often like using a howitzer to kill a pigeon and I got sick of people telling me that they can't do or fix something because "that's not how Spring works", but I've accepted that Java and Spring are like hand and glove at this point.

Ah, so those microservices are still going to be using Spring on grounds that There Is No Other Framework. Oh well. Maybe if you switch to Akka? Or do you just end up locked into both at once? ;-)

@SteveJessop All of the frameworks. Use them all. Maven makes it easy.

@SteveJessop In all seriousness, I did kind of like Bob Lee's (RIP) Guice at one point, but it didn't get enough traction.

Literally the only commercial Java programming I've ever done was writing tests for a CDC+J2ME implementation, and that was just occasional. My real work was in the implementation. So I guess the only Java "framework" I've ever actually used is the TCK loader. Seemed OK ;-)
